# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I just started receiving this exception today 2/1/21.  I have a solution below but still don't know why the initial line of code stopped working.

```
// Throws Exception
// System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.
DateTime fromDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Day, 0, 0, 0);

// This works
DateTime start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime(start.Year, start.Month, start.Day, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Day` returns the last date in January which is `31` (since today is Feb 1) and there is no day 31 in February.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Day gives 31 and February only has 28 days.

Comment: yeah, that's it.  I was using DateTime.Now for Month.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code to

```
DateTime startDateTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
```

and avoid running into this problem altogether.